# Determine the number of ways to color a 1-by-n chessboard with the colors red, blue, green and orange.

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Determine the number of ways to color a 1-by-n chessboard, using the colors red, blue, green and orange if an even number of squares is to be colored red and an even number is to be colored green.

**Current result:**

I will use exponential generating functions.
\begin{align*}
g^{(e)}(x)&=
\left(1+\frac{x^{2}}{2!}+\frac{x^{4}}{4!}+\dots\right)^2\left(1+\frac{x^{1}}{1!}+\frac{x^{2}}{2!}+\dots\right)^2\\
&=\left(\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}\right)^2e^{2x}
\\&=\frac{1}{4}\left(e^{2x}+2e^xe^{-x}+e^{-2x}\right)e^{2x}\\
&=\frac{1}{4}(e^{4x}+2e^{2x}+1)\\
&=\frac{1}{4}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}4^n\frac{x^n}{n!}+2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^n\frac{x^n}{n!}+1\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{4^n+2\times 2^n}{4}\right)\frac{x^n}{n!}+\frac{1}{4}
\end{align*}

I'm wondering how I can move $1$ into the sum? I've been suggested to use $x^0$ but I'm not certain how to incorporate that as a sum since I want to find $h_n$ which will be the coefficient of $\frac{x^n}{n!}$.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply read off the coefficients $h_n$ from the sum

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{4^n+2\cdot 2^n}4\right)\frac{x^n}{n!}+\frac14\;:$$

$h_0=\frac{1+2}4+\frac14=1$, and

$$h_n=\frac{4^n+2\cdot 2^n}4=4^{n-1}+2^{n-1}=2^{n-1}\left(2^{n-1}-1\right)$$

for $n\ge 1$.

Comment: Thank you @Brian M. Scott Could you explain why we don't need to count the $\frac{1}{4}$ for $n\geq 1$ please?

Comment: @cheeseboardqueen: Because it really is just a constant. If you write out your series ‘longhand’, you get $$\frac14+\frac34+\frac{2x}{1!}+\frac{6x^2}{2!}+\ldots\;,$$ and you can simply combine the two constant terms into one.

Comment: This helps a lot! Appreciate it :) @Brian M. Scott

Comment: @cheeseboardqueen: You’re welcome!